# conditional CSS class in ng-repeat is not working

Tags: html, css, angularjs, radio-button

I am trying to apply a css class to label if a condition becomes true for making the radio button checked, but its not working.

sample code

```
<ul style="font-size: 100%;font: inherit;">
        <li  style="margin:10px 0 0 0;" ng-repeat="condition in sampleArray">
             <label class="radio" ng-class="{checked: someCodition.conditionId == condition.conditionId}">  
                      <span class="icon"></span><span class="icon-to-fade"></span>                                  
                        <input type="radio" ng-model="previewContentCondition" ng-value="condition" ng-change="setPreviewContentFromCondition()">
                        <span ng-bind="condition.conditionName"></span>                                                 
            </label>
        </li>                               
</ul>
```

I tried changing like this but this is also not working.

```
<ul style="font-size: 100%;font: inherit;">
    <li  style="margin:10px 0 0 0;" ng-repeat="condition in sampleArray">
         <label class="{{someCodition.conditionId == condition.conditionId ? 'radio ' : 'radio checked' }}">    
             <span class="icon"></span><span class="icon-to-fade"></span>                                   
             <input type="radio" ng-model="previewContentCondition" ng-value="condition" ng-change="setPreviewContentFromCondition()">
         <span ng-bind="condition.conditionName"></span>                                                    
         </label>
    </li>                               
</ul>
```

any solution? if I apply the css directly its working fine.

**edit**

if I do someCodition.conditionId == 1, class is getting applied to all the radio labels.

Comment: use single brace and ng-class ` ng-class = { condition }`

Comment: any error in the console ? When you say "not working", you mean the class is not added ?

Comment: @ValentinCoudert, I am not getting any error, class is not getting applied to the label

Comment: @gauravbhavsar, I tried your answer but it didn't work

Comment: What is 'someCodition'? Where is it defined, and is the spelling mistake intentional?

Comment: please re-populate this bug in plunkr or jsfidlle.

Comment: @rrd someCondition is being set in other js function and spelling is intentional..

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to give name to your radio buttons. if you give same name to all radio buttons then only one will be clicked at once.

2) use ng-class instead.

3) Put `previewContentCondition` in an object `$scope.myobj.previewContentCondition`. ng-repeat makes its own scope and primitive values will not get in model when radio button clicked.

4) give unique value to radio button so then if it is checked you can get in model. i have used **$index** that can be get like `ng-repeat="condition in sampleArray track by $index"`

I made few changes. see working code below:

```
    <ul style="font-size: 100%;font: inherit;">
       {{myobj.previewContentCondition}}
    <li  style="margin:10px 0 0 0;" ng-repeat="condition in sampleArray track by $index">
         <label ng-class="{'classcolor':$index == myobj.previewContentCondition}">    
             <span class="icon"></span><span class="icon-to-fade"></span>   
             <input type="radio" name="test" ng-model="myobj.previewContentCondition" ng-checked="true" type="radio" value="{{$index}}" >
         <span ng-bind="condition.conditionName"></span>                                                    
         </label>
    </li>                               
</ul>
```

see working plnkr [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/G3WwRXQK0ENNNqYphUoq?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap `''` around the class name :

```
<label class="radio" ng-class="{'checked': someCodition.conditionId == condition.conditionId}">
```

Comment: How is your expression `someCodition.conditionId == condition.conditionId` validated?

Comment: This condition is returning value as true I have checked it by printing the condition value.

Comment: wrap ' ' around single word class name is optional. When class name is like my-class, then you should wrap it like 'my-class'. Ref: [angular ng-class](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)